# Trying to change button's contents each hit fails

Tags: javascript, html

Given the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
Something...
</head>

<button id='flip' type='button'>Flip</button>
<script>
$('#flip').bind('click', function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("flip").name;
    if (x == 'Flip')
    {
        $(this).text('Flop');
    }

    else
    {
        $(this).text('Flip');
    }

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to change the button each time it is clicked , but it doesn't work .

Any idea how to fix it ?

Much appreciated

Comment: This seriously reminds me of something that would be on the AP Compsci exam. They always love to do silly things involving tongue-twisters, like flipping and flopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `name` attribute on your `<button>`, so you'll always get empty value. No need for `document.getElementById` because button is in `this`. Simply call [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) without parameters to get current value:

```
var x = $(this).text();
```

#### Update

Here is demo in [JsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf6GA/).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="flipflop">flip</button>
```

**javascript:**

```
var flip = true;
$("#flipflop").click(function(){
    if(flip)
        $("#flipflop").text("flop");
    else
        $("#flipflop").text("flip");
    flip = !flip;
})
```

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/bt6Xj/4/)

**edit:** if you want to be really savvy, I would use the following line:

`var flip = ($("#flipflop").text() === "flip");`

Which automatically determines which way you need to flip (or is it flop?).

Comment: `var flip` should probably be declared inside click callback. Otherwise it'll be hard to have multiple flip flop buttons on the page. Not sure if OP needs multiple buttons anyway.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev, well, yeah, it depends on what he needs.